# ffmpeg hls master playlist generation

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

With the recent ffmpeg master branch(commit 7fcbeb) we can generate the master playlist using

> -master_pl_name

option. But I am unable to generate the master playlist with different profiles. Tried using

> -var_stream_map

how can we use these options for creating master playlist with different profiles?

I am trying with below ffmpeg command:

```
# ./ffmpeg  -y -loglevel error -err_detect careful -analyzeduration 8000000 -probesize 4000000 -rtbufsize 300000 -flush_packets 0 -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt -f mpegts -i test.ts -c copy -var_stream_map "v:0,agroup:aud_high a:0,agroup:aud_high" -ignore_unknown -flags global_header -f hls -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -master_pl_publish_rate 32 -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 40 -hls_flags delete_segments /webserver/video0_%v.m3u8
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the [examples](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls) for `var_stream_map`?

Comment: Checked but I could not find for different hls profile levels.

Comment: What do you understand by *hls profile levels*?

Comment: Now, I understand what you have asked for. Will try and post my result here.

Comment: `./ffmpeg  -y -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt -f mpegts -i test.ts -i test1.ts -i test2.ts -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:v -map 1:a -map 2:v -map 2:a -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,agroup:aud_low v:1,a:1,agroup:aud_medium v:2,a:2,agroup:aud_high" -ignore_unknown -flags global_header -f hls -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -master_pl_publish_rate 32 -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 40 -hls_flags delete_segments /webserver/video0_%v.m3u8` this is working fine for me. Where inputs have different resolutions. Thanks @aergistal

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because FFMpeg cannot figure out the bitrate if you are copying the streams (-c copy).  The HLS spec requires a bandwidth attribute in the master playlist, so FFMpeg will not write a master playlist without that information.

To get around this, just set the bitrates anyways, using -b:v and -b:a.  The streams will still be copied from the source, but FFMpeg will use the numbers provided and write a master playlist.

See: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7403